# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'File' because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, writefile

I'm trying to check the version of my program, if it isn't correct then it downloads it and writes the version to the file. It says it's being used by another process (I've already checked, there's no process's open that could use it)

I've tried setting the file attributes
I've tried using the assembly to replace the files, didn't work

```
File.SetAttributes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\EXE_Version.txt", FileAttributes.Normal);
File.SetAttributes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\DLL_Version.txt", FileAttributes.Normal);

StreamReader EXE_READER = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\EXE_Version.txt");
StreamReader DLL_READER = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\DLL_Version.txt");

StreamWriter EXE_WRITER = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\EXE_Version.txt", true);
StreamWriter DLL_WRITER = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\bin\\ver\\DLL_Version.txt", true);

EXE_VERSION = EXE_READER.ReadToEnd();
DLL_VERSION = DLL_READER.ReadToEnd();

string EXE_VERSION_READ = string.Empty;
string DLL_VERSION_READ = string.Empty;

HttpWebRequest EXE_REQUEST = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://link/exe_version.txt");
using (HttpWebResponse EXE_RESPONSE = (HttpWebResponse)EXE_REQUEST.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream EXE_STREAM_URL = EXE_RESPONSE.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader EXE_READER_URL = new StreamReader(EXE_STREAM_URL))
    {
        EXE_VERSION_READ = EXE_READER_URL.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

HttpWebRequest DLL_REQUEST = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://link/dll_version.txt");
using (HttpWebResponse DLL_RESPONSE = (HttpWebResponse)DLL_REQUEST.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream DLL_STREAM_URL = DLL_RESPONSE.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader DLL_READER_URL = new StreamReader(DLL_STREAM_URL))
    {
        DLL_VERSION_READ = DLL_READER_URL.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

if (EXE_VERSION_READ != EXE_VERSION)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Found an update, downloading...");
    client.DownloadFile("https://link/EXE_Latest.html", "Zuros.exe");
    EXE_WRITER.WriteLine(EXE_VERSION_READ);
    EXE_WRITER.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded EXE version: " + EXE_VERSION_READ);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Executable updates were found, checking for DLL updates.");
}
```

I want to change the version in the version file to the version from the version stored on the website so that it doesn't say there's an update every time you launch.

Comment: In which .exe is this code contained?

Comment: you need to wrap your readers in `using` statements

Comment: The other process is a lie - it's *your own process*. You have the files open for reading, and you never specified that you were happy for someone to write to them at the same time (vice versa for the writers). Completely separate the reading from the writing and, as vasily.sib says, employ `using` statements too.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever im kinda confused, I dont know how to use them. I never have, could you provide some assistance?

Comment: Both `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` do implement `IDisposable`. That interface means those clases handle resources that must be closed/freed explicitly. If you dont free your resources they may locked/busy until your application ends and you could have trouble accesing the files. Check [using statements - IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

Comment: @bradbury9 I tried this, still says the same error
https://pastebin.com/raw/ccqsNzrC

Comment: Just make sure you close the streams after using the streams.  The error is occurring the 2nd time you try to open the streams because they are already opened.  The current code if you get an exception may not close the streams.  My preference is to use a try/catch instead of a using so when exceptions occur you can make sure the streams close.

Comment: @jdweng A using statement is a try catch under the covers and will dispose the object when exceptions occur.

Comment: @juharr : I've seen cases where that doesn't happen especially when you have nested methods and exception happens at a lower level method that is unhandled.  The catch in the using seems to miss the lower level exceptions.